# No MyUser matches the given query

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am having an error No MyUser matches the given query, and I am not sure why there is no a match since the URL is properly set.

In my app I have two kind of users: Employees and candidates that are both part of the model MyUser and are differentiated by a boolean is_candidate or is_employee.

My issue is when creating the user detail view. 
I started with the EmployeeDetailView :

```
class EmployeeDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = MyUser
    template_name = 'employee_details.html'


    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(MyUser, pk=self.kwargs['pk2'], members__project=self.kwargs['pk1'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        employee_name = MyUser.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk2'])
        team_list = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
        team_list_pop = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all().exclude(id=self.kwargs['pk2'])

        context={
            'employee_name' : employee_name,
            'team_list' : team_list,
            'team_list_pop' : team_list_pop,
        }
        return context
```

on URL : `url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/$',views.EmployeeDetailView.as_view(), name='EmployeeDetails'),`

That work properly and I am able to access my user detail
So I wanted to do the same for CandidateDetailView with the code :

```
class CandidateDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = MyUser
    template_name = 'employee_details.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        print(self.kwargs['pk2'])
        return get_object_or_404(MyUser, pk=self.kwargs['pk2'], applicant__project=self.kwargs['pk1'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CandidateDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context={

        }
        return context
```

On URL : `url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/$',views.CandidateDetailView.as_view(), name='CandidateDetails'),`

But this time I get the error that there is no matching 
Raised by:  website.views.EmployeeDetailView

My model:

```
class Project(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey('registration.MyUser', blank=True, null=True)
    candidat_answers = models.ManyToManyField('survey.response')
    applicant = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="applicant")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk1' : self.pk})

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    team_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="members")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name
```

What am I doing wrong ? 
I am getting the error on the URL :http://127.0.0.1:8000/website/project/54/43/ where 54 is Project ID and 43 is User ID both exist and User ID 43 is part of project 54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/$',views.EmployeeDetailView.as_view(), name='EmployeeDetails'),
url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/$',views.CandidateDetailView.as_view(), name='CandidateDetails')
```

Both of these URL patterns have the same regex. If the `EmployeeDetails` URL pattern comes first, then it will always be used.

You need to change the regex for the views, so that they do not clash, for example:

```
url(r'^project/employee/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/$',views.EmployeeDetailView.as_view(), name='EmployeeDetails'),
url(r'^project/candidate/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/$',views.CandidateDetailView.as_view(), name='CandidateDetails')
```